# transfer 16 bit pattern into another register by left shifting

Tags: c

I'm in the way to implement double dabble algorithm in C to perform binary to BCD notation. I'm using a pic16f876a. I'm not sure, but i guess there's no default operation to do this, so i want to transfer/left shift  one bit at a time from the original register to another in this fashion:

```
0000 0000 0000   11110011   Initialization
0000 0000 0001   11100110  < Left Shift
0000 0000 0011   11001100   <Left Shift
0000 0000 0111   10011000  < Left Shift
add 3 to nibble with 7/111 result ...
```

I will start by creating 16bits register
should i mask the original number's MSB and place it on LSB of the other register? and then lef shift original register?

And eventually get to his final BCD result

```
       BCD          (Binary)
100s Tens Ones    Original 
0010 0100 0011   11110011
```

I don't know how to drag every individual bit 
Also i know i'll have to add 3 when nibble is greater than 4, but maybe masking will do the job.I'll be displaying four digits in 7 segment display from 0000 to 3000 i'll be getting from multiplying 16bit resgiter for a constant to get a maximum of 3000 when register is 1111 1111 1111 1111.

thanks in advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively here is a simple way to convert an integer to BCD (not using the double dabble algorithm). It uses sprintf+strtod:

```
unsigned to_BCD(unsigned x) {
  char s[20]; // enough even for 64-bits integers !
  sprintf(s, "0x%u", x);
  return (unsigned) strtod(s, NULL); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. The `main()` displays the result in hexadecimal (which must correspond to the initial decimal integer).

NB: you can replace all `unsigned` by any **unsigned** integer type. For instance by `uint16_t` for a 16 bits integer (don't forget `#include <stdint.h>`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned double_dabble(unsigned x) {
  unsigned r = 0, mask, d;
  int k = 0, nibbles, n, bit;

  for(mask = 1 << (sizeof(x) * 8 - 1); mask; mask >>= 1) {
    nibbles = (++k + 3) / 4;
    for(n = 0; n < nibbles; n++) {
      d = r & (0b1111 << (n * 4));
      if (d > (4 << (n * 4)))
        r += 3 << (n * 4);
    }
    bit = ((x & mask) != 0);
    r = (r << 1) | bit;

  }
  return r;
}

int main() {
  unsigned x = 0b11110011; // 423
  printf("x: %d -> BCD: %x\n", x, double_dabble(x));
}
```

Comment: 10Q so much, all review both. Have a great week.